# Better Magic Wormhole alternative

Tags: file-synchronization, data-transfer

I'm fed up with Magic Wormhole. I once stumbled upon an alternative program that claimed to do thing better, but I simply cannot find it any more. I only recall that it linked a blog post explaining the details why it was better and that it is written in Rust. If someone dug it out for me (despite the little information) that would be awesome, but otherwise here are equivalent requirements:

- File transfer functionality similar to [Magic Wormhole](https://github.com/warner/magic-wormhole)
- Security model similar to Magic Wormhole
- Transfer folders/multiple files without zipping them first
- Not a hassle to install (the python dependency zoo is quite frustrating; think of those poor Windows users. Even the Arch Linux package was broken for quite a while)
- Linux and Windows support

Comment: I've just added a link to the project for those who don't know it. It might help if you'd specify what parts of the security concept you're after, for those not familiar with it. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit (a couple of years later):** After having finally found the application I had been looking for, I could try it out and it had its issues too. So instead I decided it would be best to invest my time in improving Magic Wormhole instead of Croc or any alternative (there are quite a few, nowadays).

One of the previous pain points, Windows support, has been resolved with the release of [Rust](https://github.com/magic-wormhole/magic-wormhole.rs) and [Go](https://github.com/psanford/wormhole-william) clients. There are GUIs too and a web UI is work in progress.

The other major pain point, having to zip folders before sending, is being worked on (I'll update this answer when it's there if I remember).

---

*Original answer:*

I found it! (As usual, the best way to get answers to problems is to ask them on StackExchange and then wait until the answer magically manifests itself ^^)

It's called [croc](https://github.com/schollz/croc). [Here's the blog post](https://schollz.com/blog/croc6/).

- CLI application that works like Wormhole
- Uses PAKE for security as well
- Supports multiple file and resuming interrupted downloads
- Not written in Rust, but Go produces static binaries as well so that's fine
- Packaged for Nix and Arch. Claims to have Windows support but I did not test it yet (generally Go binaries are *really* portable, for better or worse)

Comment: Croc is know to have security issues: https://redrocket.club/posts/croc/ Personally I don't recommend to use it despite the fact that they has been fixed.